# Understanding runtime of this python function

Tags: python, runtime

```
def loopy_loop(n):
  for i in range(n):
    for j in range(i):
      if j*j > i:
        break
```

Where n is a positive integer.

Let's say I take n=10

The outer loop will run n times for sure (n=10 times)
The inner loop will run based on the values.

- n = 0, the inner loop runs 0 times
- n=1, the inner loop runs once
- n=2, the inner loop runs 3 times
- n=3, the inner loop runs 4 times(until j=3, and 9>3)
- n=4, the inner loop runs 4 times as well
- and so on until n=9, where it will run 5 times

I'm having difficulties putting everything together to express the runtime using big O notation. Is there a set algorithm that could help me for this specific snippet of code an others?

Answer (score 2):

The outer loop runs `n` times.

The inner loop runs `sqrt(i)` times (because when `i` is given it stops when `j**2` reaches `i`) but `i` grows (roughly) like `n` (`n//2` average)

The complexity is `O(n**1.5)`  (`n` times square root of `n`)

More accurate estimate:

```
def loopy_loop(n):
    counter=0
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i):
            counter+=1
            if j*j > i:
                break
    return counter,int((n)*(n//2)**0.5)

print(loopy_loop(5))
print(loopy_loop(10))
print(loopy_loop(100))
print(loopy_loop(1000))
print(loopy_loop(15000))
```

result (count vs estimate):

```
(10, 7)
(31, 22)
(810, 707)
(22579, 22360)
(1247250, 1299038)
```

Comment: thank you for the solution. I should have mentioned this   will have to be done with pen and paper alone, no computer.

Comment: you have the pen & paper version above,

Comment: Is the idea to basically plug in a few numbers, and see how many steps the function takes to complete for each number?

Comment: the counting program is more to convince that you're right about the estimate, but a code analysis is enough. I had my idea of `n**1.5` without counting. It's because when given `n` to the inner loop, it stops after `n**0.5` times because of the square computation.